# Paypal API response contains undocumented field

Tags: php, paypal

I am using the API method `GetTransactionDetails` to retreive a transaction detail from Paypal.

In the response, I get this field `SHIPHANDLEAMOUNT` with value `0.00`. However, this field is [**NOT in the documentation at all**](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/).

Does anyone know why this is the case? I am worried there may be other fields I might miss capturing.

I am using the latest version of Paypal's classic API: `119.0` (updated November 11th 2014). And the transaction I am getting details for was completed only 5 days ago.